# How to query for unique pages views by date, IP

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table
--------
Date CreatedOn
varchar(25) IP
```

From this table, I want to selected the number of unique IP addresses, by Day.

```
June 1, 2013       25
June 2, 2013       35
June 3, 2013        0
```

Note, the third item was added after original question to deal with days with no items.  The data will be turned into a chart/graph.

What is the Sql Server 2008R2 SQL for this?

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY date
```

if you want to have unique count, you need to have `DISTINCT`, eg. `COUNT(DISTINCT IP)`.

*follow-up question: is there a date that has no view? what are you going to do with it?*

---

Since you want to show all dates between two date range according to your comment, you need to have a calendar table or something that generates all the dates between the date range.

```
-- let's say 
-- start date = June 1, 2013
-- end date = June 5, 2013


WITH DateTimeSequence
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20130601' as datetime) AS [datetime]    -- Start Date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, [datetime])
  FROM   DateTimeSequence
  WHERE  DATEADD(d, 1, [datetime]) <= CAST('20130605' as datetime) -- End Date
)
SELECT a.[datetime],
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.[ipaddress]) uniqueIP_Count
FROM   DateTimeSequence a
        LEFT JOIN TableName b
          ON a.[datetime] = b.[date]
GROUP BY a.[datetime]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b12c/7)

Comment: I don't understand the follow up question.

Comment: example, `June 1, 2013 => 25`, `June 3, 2013 => 3`. will `June 2, 2013` included on the list with `0` view?

Comment: I see.  Good point.  Yes, that would be useful if possible. The data will be turned into a Graph, so that would be good.

Comment: what version of sql server you are using? do you have certain date range?

Comment: Am using Sql Server 2008R2.  Yes, a date range will be passed in.

Comment: Is this a table? or is it a view? Do you left join somewhere?

Comment: No, it's not a view.  Just a simple table.

Comment: you need something that generates sequential date since you still want to appear dates that have no view from IP.

Comment: Thank you @491243 That is a very nice SQL Solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CreatedOn,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IP)
FROM   Table
GROUP BY CreatedOn
```

Comment: Thanks, the Distinct is what I was missing.